# How to split Polygons by line grid?

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-plugins, splitting, polygonize

I want to split a polygon by a intersecting line into different parts, exactly like in this  post([Split a polygon layer with a line layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36934/qgis-is-there-a-way-to-split-a-polygon-layer-with-a-line-layer)).

I have a vector grid to cut the polygons, so I used the intersect tool(vector grid with polygons) first, to get the lines from the vector grid intersecting the polygons I want to cut.

Afterwards I followed the procedure like in the post mentioned above (union and then polygonize), but it does not provide a feasible solution, because some layers are cut as I want it and others are not.

Does anyone has any workaround about it? I read here  ([Making polygon from intersecting lines in QGIS using Polygonize or similar?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85452/make-a-polygon-from-intersecting-lines-in-qgis-using-polygonize-or-similar) ) that there have been some problems with polygonize, maybe this is the reason?

FYI: I am running Windows 8, 64 bit, QGIS Desktop 2.4, and installed it by the downloaded file.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to poligonize the grid and to then intersect the polygon grid with the other input polygon layer. That should be much less trouble.