# QGIS installation failed - requires matplotlib which has been installed by Anaconda

Tags: qgis, installation, mac, matplotlib, anaconda

Is there any way to specify python environment variable to solve this?

When I tried to install QGIS on my machine - mac OS 10.9 and Anaconda has installed numpy, scipy, and matplotlib, I got the error message:

> matplotlib was requires.

Comment: look at [OS X Python vs QGIS Python](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82759/os-x-python-vs-qgis-python/82773#82773) or [QGIS Python version](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/51893/qgis-python-version/51911#51911) or [QGIS 2 Python error on Mac OSX](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72059/qgis-2-python-error-on-mac-osx/72073#72073) or [QGIS on Mavericks](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80856/qgis-on-mavericks/80872#80872)

Comment: If you use the [Kyng Chaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis) version, Matplotlib need to be installed in the Apple Python (the Anaconda Python is not recognized)